# Tiles is not passing form:errors to jsp in spring mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, tiles

So apparently when going through tiles view resolver the binding result gets lost and  doesnt work in spring mvc.

e.g. even though (result.hasErrors()>0), the error objects are not passed to the model when going through tiles. Is this a know bug in tiles/spring?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it and it works fine. Just ensure that your form:errors tag is under your form:form tag or if not ensure that they use the same "commandName" as your BindingResult object (and use  spring tag in your tiles view).